# get table prefix

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

is there any way to obtain the table prefix after connect to the database ?

I'm using wordpress and I need to obtain the table prefix but outside the whole wordpress installation. Currently my script connect to the database, but I need the table prefix to incorporate in some parts of the script.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see below answer, if it works, please accept the answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<?php
    $root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
    require "$root/wp-blog-header.php";

    function get_table_prefix() {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_prefix = $wpdb->prefix . "outsider_plugin";
        return $table_prefix;
    }
    // echo get_table_prefix();
?>
```

Thanks mack, your idea help me to solve the problem, using a similar approach.

Answer (score 7):

Create any PHP file, outside WordPress,

```
<?php
    require('wp-blog-header.php');
    echo $wpdb->base_prefix;
?>
```

Please use correct path for `wp-blog-header.php` in `require`

Comment: Possibly the same one that closed the question (now reopened).

Comment: Note, $base_prefix is probably not what you want if the WordPress site is part of a multisite setup.